# How to parse this string in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I would like to understand how you would parse the below string in Java. Basically, I want everything between the text "Begin-Data" and "End-Data"

```
Begin-Data
abc
123
End-Data
```

Comment: indexOf and substring for a good ol' fashion way.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner solution uses `String#replaceAll`:

```java
String input = "Begin-Data abc 123 End-Data";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?s).*\\bBegin-Data\\s+(.*?)\\s+End-Data\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);  // abc 123
```

This answer assumes that the input string only contains the starting/ending tags `Begin-Data` and `End-Data` once.  If you have many such tags, then you should use a formal regex pattern matcher:

```java
String input = "Begin-Data abc 123 End-Data Begin-Data abc 345 End-Data";
String pattern = "(?s)\\bBegin-Data\\s+(.*?)\\s+End-Data\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find( )) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(matches);  // [abc 123, abc 345]
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat My assumption was that the OP only expected one single pair of tags.  In the case of your input above, we should use a formal pattern matcher, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: The King of Regex - chances of being downvoted < 10% ;-)

Comment: Actually [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is the all-time regex king on this site AFAIK.  I do get a few points on the regex tag here and there, when he's sleeping `;-)`

Comment: Yep, I never try to answer a Regex when he is awake.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.  I will try different approaches and see how it goes.  This was exactly want I was seeking.